# LSTM Text Classification Bad Accuracy Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I'm going crazy in this project. This is multi-label text-classification with lstm in keras. My model is this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(max_features, embeddings_dim, input_length=max_sent_len, mask_zero=True, weights=[embedding_weights] ))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=embeddings_dim , activation='sigmoid', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(activation='sigmoid', units=embeddings_dim, recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.04)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Only that I have too low an accuracy .. with the binary-crossentropy I get a good accuracy, but the results are wrong !!!!! changing to categorical-crossentropy, I get very low accuracy. Do you have any suggestions?

there is my code: [GitHubProject - Multi-Label-Text-Classification](http://github.com/ancileddu/multi-label-text-classification)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In last layer, the activation function you are using is `sigmoid`, so `binary_crossentropy` should be used. Incase you want to use `categorical_crossentropy` then use `softmax` as activation function in last layer.

Now, coming to the other part of your model, since you are working with text, i would tell you to go for `tanh` as activation function in LSTM layers.

And you can try using LSTM's dropouts as well like `dropout` and `recurrent dropout`

```
LSTM(units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,
                             activation='tanh')
```

You can define units as `64` or `128`. Start from small number and after testing you take them till `1024`.

You can try adding `convolution` layer as well for extracting features or use `Bidirectional LSTM` But models based `Bidirectional` takes time to train.

Moreover, since you are working on text, `pre-processing of text and size of training data` always play much bigger role than expected.

**Edited**

Add Class weights in fit parameter

```
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                  np.unique(labels),
                                                  labels)
class_weights_dict = dict(zip(le.transform(list(le.classes_)),
                          class_weights))


model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split, class_weight=class_weights_dict)
```

Comment: thank you!! i use categorical_crossentropy because i have multiple class to predict..is correct??? can i use binary for this purpose??? Now i use softmax and tanh but accuracy is still low. How can i use LSTM's dropouts as well like dropout and recurrent dropout??? for the pre-processing i use 
`embeddings = dict( )
embeddings = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz" , binary=True) ` is correct??

Comment: @angelocurtigiardina You can use `binary_crossentropy` if you are using `softmax` and check the answer, I have edited.

Comment: have you tried using pre-trained glove and fasttext? @angelocurtigiardina

Comment: really really thank's! with binary the accuracy is high!!!! now i'm testing..then i try with glove and fasttext!!!! really thank's! @UpasanaMittal

Comment: Really bad :( my code is this..tried with word2vec and fasttext, binary and categorical..with binary the accuracy is high but the result are incorrect..what am I doing wrong? ......i'm not able to post my code..

Comment: @angelocurtigiardina can you tell me size of your data and number of samples per class? And did you add conv layer?

Comment: If you can post your code on github then do let me know. I will check.

Comment: there is my code: https://github.com/ancileddu/multi-label-text-classification .. i can't add the conv layer because the teacher just wants lstm :( really thank you! you're very kind! it's my last university exam and I'm going crazy!!!!

Comment: Please explain me one thing. Why are you training word2vec on negative words but not on the data you are training your model on?

Comment: it's an error..now i've changed with embeddings = gensim.models.Word2Vec(train_texts, min_count=1, size=300)..is correct???

Comment: You haven't done text cleaning. any particular reason?

Comment: it is necessary? practically I have to remove from the trainset the useless words and the punctuation ??

Comment: sorry, i'm noob..'tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True, split=" ")' this cose clean data, no?

Comment: What is the total number of samples per class?

Comment: class 0: 808 -
class 1: 1652 -
class 2: 1220 -
class 3: 1708 -
class 4: 969

Comment: There is class imbalance. I am editing answer with giving class_weights as dict in fit parameter. Please do that as well.

Comment: labels are labels = ["0","1","2","3","4"] right? now the error is: `class_weight` must contain all classes in the data. The classes {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} exist in the data but not in `class_weight`..i'm going crazy..


model.fit(train_sequences, train_labels, validation_split=0.1, class_weight=class_weights_dict)

Comment: I checked your code. and done changes accordingly again. Use it. And I am trying the model with  the data provided at my end as well.

Comment: i'm very grateful for your precious help..thank you very much!!!!!! but my model doesn't provide an accurate prediction :( how many epochs should i use? i've tried with 1 and 5..

Comment: use early callback in fit parameter and try epoch atleast 50

Comment: @angelocurtigiardina can you please check this https://github.com/upasana-mittal/stackoverflow/blob/master/sentence-classification.py

Comment: Please try changing glove embedding to other as i have tried with twitter one. You can try with wikipedia one.https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
and use `100` dimension only.

Comment: this is really really cool!!!!!!!!! thank you very much..now i commit all the mod..you are the best!!!!!!!! now i'm trying the model with 50 epochs..good!!!!

Answer (score 4):

change:

```
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

to:

```
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```